# Add display banner for iOS app on iTunes Store

Tags: app-store, app-store-connect, banner

I want to show a marketing banner for my iOS app on the App Store like Tinder and Chillar do. How can I do this in iTunes Connect? Here is a screenshot of what I am referring to:

[image: iTunes Store screenshot of Tinder]

Answer (score 9):

You can't. Your app has to be featured on the App Store to display those banners. If your app is in the process to become featured Apple will send you an email with the requests for those images. (http://blog.cleanshavenapps.com/app-store-promo-artwork-tips-and-sketch-template)